# my s3 lock screen is all black

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My galaxy s3 lock screen is black. No time or shortcuts at the bottom. I went into the settings and couldn't find anything to change this. I deleted an app I thought was causing it..but nothing. I even tried to change the wallpaper and nothing happened. I also checked for  viruses but I have none. Someone please help me get my lock screen wallpaper back

Comment: I don't know what you mean by one

Answer (score 0):

Re-install with kias or because samsung dropped support gor it, if you want a secure ROM use CM;

https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/D2att_Info